# Can you access users' browsing history?

Tags: cookies, browser-history

I came across the following paragraph.

> In the run-up to the 2012 presidential election, the Romney and Obama campaigns followed voters across the web by installing cookies on their computers and observing the websites they visited in an attempt to gather information on their personal views. CampaignGrid, a Republican affiliated firm, and Precision Network, a Democratic affiliated firm, both worked to collect data on 150 million American Internet users, or 80% of the registered voting population.

source: http://www.theinternetofthings.eu/john-whitehead-eyesee-you-and-internet-things-watching-you-while-you-shop

I would like to do that myself but is it possible to read the browser history or access cookies other websites created? I thought Javascript prevented (or was unable to do) this.